# Get boxplot stats of a column separated by values in another column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, subset, boxplot, summary, quantile

I have a data frame like this:

```
distance exclude   
1.1    F
1.5    F
3      F
2      F
1      F
5      T
3      F
63     F
32     F
21     F
15     F
1      T
```

I want get the four boxplot stats of each segment of data in distance column separated by "T" in exclude column, here "T" serves as separator.

Can anyone help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is "T" A value in `exclude` or do you want that row deleted? A separator?

Comment: @akash87,Kind of a separator, not delete the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's create some fake data:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(49349)
dat = data.frame(distance=rnorm(500, 50, 10), 
                 exclude=sample(c("T","F"), 500, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.03,0.95)))
```

Now create a new group each time `exclude` = "T". Then, for each group, and calculate whatever statistics you wish and return the results in a data frame:

```
box.stats = dat %>% 
  mutate(group = cumsum(exclude=="T")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(data.frame(n=length(.$distance), 
                out_90 = sum(.$distance > quantile(.$distance, 0.9)),
                out_10 = sum(.$distance < quantile(.$distance, 0.1)),
                MEAN = round(mean(.$distance),2), 
                SD = round(sd(.$distance),2),
                out_2SD_high = sum(.$distance > mean(.$distance) + 2*sd(.$distance)),
                round(t(quantile(.$distance, probs=c(0,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))),2)))

names(box.stats) = gsub("X(.*)\\.$", "p\\1", names(box.stats))

box.stats
```

> ```
>    group     n out_90 out_10  MEAN    SD out_2SD_high    p0   p10   p25   p50   p75   p90  p100
> 1      0    15      2      2 46.21  8.78            0 28.66 36.03 41.88 46.04 52.33 56.30 61.98
> 2      1    36      4      4 50.03 10.01            0 21.71 38.78 44.63 51.13 56.66 61.58 67.84
> 3      2    80      8      8 50.36  9.00            1 20.30 38.10 45.95 51.28 56.51 61.74 70.44
> 4      3     9      1      1 55.62  8.58            0 42.11 47.10 49.19 54.54 63.63 65.84 67.88
> 5      4    16      2      2 47.70  7.79            0 29.03 39.89 43.60 49.26 52.92 56.97 58.02
> 6      5    66      7      7 49.86  9.93            2 24.84 36.00 45.05 50.51 55.65 61.41 75.27
> 7      6    44      5      5 50.35 10.39            1 31.72 36.36 43.49 50.95 55.78 64.88 73.64
> 8      7    80      8      8 49.18  9.24            1 27.62 37.86 42.06 50.34 56.60 59.66 72.13
> 9      8    31      3      3 52.56 11.18            0 25.78 39.94 44.10 51.32 62.02 66.35 70.40
> 10     9    60      6      6 50.31  9.82            1 25.43 37.44 44.53 50.31 56.78 62.36 71.77
> 11    10    33      4      4 49.99  9.78            2 32.74 38.72 42.56 49.60 55.75 62.86 72.20
> 12    11    30      3      3 48.26 11.47            1 30.03 37.68 40.24 45.65 55.42 60.18 79.36
> ```

Comment: ,what if I just want to get the return of function "boxplot.stats", since I want to see how many outliers.

Comment: See updated code. Rather than using `boxplot.stats`, which returns a list, it might be easier to customize the code to calculate whatever statistics you wish for each group, and add that to the summary data frame. For example, above I've included not only quantiles, but the number of observations in each group, the number of observations less than the 10th percentile, the mean, etc.

Comment: ,So much thanks for your help. By the way where do you learn this? Any documents might be helpful, I dont know it could be done like this.

Comment: Over the years, I've learned by a combination of Stack Overflow, package vignettes, experimentation on my own, online tutorials, and (occasionally) books. For what I've shown above, you need to learn `dplyr` (and you should also learn to use the related packages `reshape2` and `tidyr`), which make data munging much easier (also check out `data.table`, another great package for manipulating data). Start with the [`dplyr` vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: One more question, i don't quite get the "gsub" function here. How does it correct the names? (I mean I know what gsub does, but don't get it here)

Comment: Take a look at the names without `gsub`. You can see that `quantile` returns names like `X0.`, `X10.`, etc. I've used `gsub` to keep only the number (by using the capture group `(.*)`, where `.*` means any sequence of characters; I could have also done `([0-9]*)`, which would have been more specific, but I was lazy) while getting rid of the leading `X` and the final `.`, and then I add a "p" (for "percentile").

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Great to know these things from you! Thanks a lot, il keep learning and help ours later.